# x86-64 MASM: trying to use an array of labels, getting error LNK2017. Do I actually need /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO?

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2015, x86-64, linker-errors, masm

In my .asm file, I have:

```
.DATA

labels QWORD l_0, l_1, l_2, l_3, l_4, l_5, l_ret
```

and elsewhere, snippets that look like:

```
    ...
    jmp [labels+rax]
l_2:
    ...
```

now, these are giving me

```
LNK2017 'ADDR32' relocation to 'labels' invalid without /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO
```

and I can find that option in my project properties, but I'm hesitating for a few reasons.  First is that I'm pretty new to this, and I'm not confident that I even have the syntax correct for what I'm trying to accomplish (which is jumping to a location marked by the label in slot rax of an array of labels).  Secondly, I'm a little wary at the suggestion that I need to change my linker settings for what I should think is (under the hood) a fairly routine 64bit addition.

Then again, maybe my instincts are totally wrong here and I ought to change that setting.  I'm hoping the internet can set me straight here.